# Android layout doesn't stretch on full screen

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with layout which won't stretch within high resolution like 1024x600.

As root layout I use RelativeLayout with following style:

```
 <style name="DefaultLayout">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
 </style>
```

I want to stretch layout to any screen resolution but on emulator with high resolution it looks like this:

[image]

If it's important I didn't use images with fixed size, header and footer it's a 1px vertical line which duplicates horizontally and the list items implemented as shapes... so there is no point where it may took some fixed size... maybe I am checking this in a wrong way... Actually I didn't figured out what is the problem

Comment: That layout will stretch to the whole screen

Comment: Does this also happen on real device (vs emulator)? Probably post your layout xml?

Comment: Did you solved it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you have not added proper screen support attributes in your AndroidManifest and the application as a whole is being scaled to part of the screen.

Read these

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: Thanks man, it helped me, in particular  <supports-screens declaration in manifest

Comment: Dear Friend, my app work on 1080p Display. I followed your way but didn't.

Comment: [code]    <supports-screens
        android:resizeable="false"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="960"
    android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="960"
    android:largestWidthLimitDp="960"/>